# C# Modelling turn based rounds system with different rules

Tags: c#

I'm taking my first steps in C#.

I'm building a turned based cards game that goes through several rounds and each round has different rules than the one before.

These rules are known beforehand. In some rounds there are suits that the player cant play, in other rounds there are trump suits. In each round 4 players take turns playing all 13 cards they have each. Then the deck is reshuffled / re dealt and a new round with different rules starts.

I'm a bit stuck in trying to model this in C#

I have my basic Card / Deck classes done with the usual shuffle deck and deal hand methods, but I'm struggling on the best way to implement this rounds system.

**Can you help with the class /function modelling? I can code it from there.**

thanks!
Pedro

Comment: I am non-beginner, and I can't even figure out what the subject is about.  Simplify things, please.

Comment: thanks for your answers guys, the strategy pattern was what i was looking for. very helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the strategy pattern.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Answer (score 1):

Have a base class for your rule and implement each specific rule for each round.  Outside of this class, have some logic that knows what specific rule to give you based on the current round, and then use the shared logic (something like, IsValidMove?) that you would have overridden in each derived class.

```
public abstract class BaseRule
    {
        public virtual bool IsValidMove(object moveDescription);
    }

    public class Round1Rule : BaseRule
    {
        public override bool IsValidMove(object moveDescription)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Round2Rule : BaseRule
    {
        public override bool IsValidMove(object moveDescription)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Player`s would interface, through the `Table` they are playing on, with the current set of `Rule`s currently valid.

At the end of each turn, `Table` sets its `current_rule` field to the appropriate subclass of `Rule` that needs to be used for the next turn.

`Rule` subtypes would expose methods like `bool is_legal_to_play(Card card, ...)` or `int get_score_for(Player player, ...)`, or even AI-facilitating methods like `float rate_move(Card card, ...)` (then actually play the one with the max rate_move value).

`Table` would expose methods/properties like `Rule get_current_rules()`, `Player get_current_player()`, `Player get_player_to_the_right_of(Player player)`, ...

<sub>Please note I do not have actually any C# experience; this is a pretty much generic OOP scheme that does not adhere to any particular template. Sue me.</sub>

<sup>Ellipses cover additional parameters that may be required depending on what your rules are.</sup>